# sending message from topViewController to rootViewController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an application for iPhone in which I need to send a message from `topViewController` to `rootViewController`.

One solution might be that make delegate methods in each VC in navigation stack and call accordingly so that message will reach at `rootViewController`. But in this scenario message has to pass through whole navigation stack.

Can any body help me on this with best approach

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to access `rootViewcontroller` as,

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then do the necessary operation on this object. `navigationController.viewControllers` returns all the viewControllers in the navigation stack.

Comment: thanks, i used the same method, but someone said that it can cause a circular dependency sort of thing and can cause memory leaks etc please advise

Comment: @AbdusSamad, This wont cause any circular dependency. `navigationController.viewControllers` is a property available to navigationController and it can be used anywhere. In this case you are just accessing the first object and doing something on that. Make sure you are not retaining it in your class.

Answer (score 1):

In any of the topViewController methods you can extract the navigation stacks's rootViewController
by

```
 [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Isn't this same as the answer posted below?

Comment: @ACB:Yeah..perhaps ..i was fraction of a second late posting this :B